# Conductivity of silver

Tags: electrical-resistance, conductors

What makes silver the best conductor of electricity?
I want to know in terms of electrons. Although, Cu and Ag and many other metals have only one electron in their valence shell. Then what makes Ag the best conductor?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293019/247580 this might help you

Comment: This question has no answer in the above link. Only different attempts at answer.